# If constructor in SFMC query

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

How to do if conditioning within SQL statements

```
SELECT su.emailAddress,
IF C.SubscriberKey IS alphanumeric THEN ''
ELSE C.SubscriberKey AS SUBSCRIBERKEY
FROM from [_CLICK] C
join [_SUBSCRIBERS] su
on su.SubscriberKey =C.SubscriberKey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use CASE - WHEN - THEN - END constructs in Marketing Cloud, as Microsoft SQL is used in the background.

It somewhat looks like this:

```sql
CASE input_expression   
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
END
```

I'm not sure if your `is alphanumeric` expression works, but if it doesn't you could also try using something like `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9A-Za-z]%'`. However, if it does, your query looks like this (I also removed the second from keyword):

```sql
SELECT
    su.emailAddress,
    CASE
        WHEN C.SubscriberKey IS alphanumeric THEN ''
        ELSE C.SubscriberKey
    END AS SUBSCRIBERKEY
FROM [_CLICK] C
JOIN [_SUBSCRIBERS] su
ON su.SubscriberKey = C.SubscriberKey
```

**Further documentation:**

- [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)